# EPISERVER 6 R2 Selected/not selected default value not working

Tags: episerver

I am trying to set default value for Selected/not selected property to true in Episerver>Admin>My page type>Edit property. This should create a checkbox which is checked when creating new pages using My page type. However, after creating a new page, the checkbox is still not checked.

The same issue is with current, not new pages which use My page template.

I have tried setting  Selected/not selected property in the code behind and this worked, however, i would like to use built in functionality so i could have more control.

I would appreciate some advise/help. Is it Episerver bug or something i am missing?

p.s i posted the same question on episerver forum but didnt get any replies

Answer (score 1):

Setting the default value to 'True' on the Selected/not selected property should work...

[image: Set the Default value to 'True']

I tested this on a clean install of CMS 6 R2 and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a new page using Episerver menu and the checkbox was checked. However, we do create some pages programatically using CreateWritableClone, and the pages are based on another default page, which did not have the checkbox checked. This was the cause of my problem. All i had to do is check it and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Existing page instances will not be affected after making changes to page type definition property mandatory settings.
As mentioned - Specifying default value 'True' should be working. Tested on clean installation.
Are you creating page types manually or using PageTypeBuilder?